# Get the Row Positions without Looping

Tags: excel, vba, loops, search, match

Is it possible to get the row positions in a large table in excel without performing a loop?
What I am trying to do is to click on a particular ID, and then the last 3 records from the same ID will be shown in UI.

I am beginner in programming and have no idea how to do this aside from looping method (which is very resource and memory-intensive considering we are looping a large and growing table of 100k rows in every single click from user).

For example: If user is clicking "A123" then we know that their row positions are : 5, 8 , 10

[image]

Comment: If you hae 100k of rows you should consider using an SQL database where this is easily possible. • In Excel you could use filters to filter for `A123` but without looping you still won't get the first 3.

Comment: @PEH - we dont have that option to use SQL database unfortunately... For your suggestion on using filter, is it possible to loop filtered table? Would you kindly show some sample code on how to do this? thanks!

Comment: Well then filter, loop or powerqueries are your options I guess. Have a look into it and give it a try.

Comment: not exactly the same but maybe an acceptable compromise is to add a helper col with "=row()" and show the info in a pivotTable with a slicer. performance could even be improved by adding the source to the datamodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as CDP1802 posted but faster finding of last 3 rows.

```
Sub FilteredAdvanced()
    Const nValues As Long = 3 'amount of rows you want to find from the end
    
    Dim ar() As Long
    ReDim ar(nValues - 1) As Long
    
    ' apply filter
    With Sheet1
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, "A123"
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter 'remove filter
    End With
    
    Dim n As Long
    n = nValues - 1

    Dim iArea As Long
    For iArea = rng.Areas.Count To 1 Step -1
        Dim iRow As Long
        For iRow = rng.Areas(iArea).Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            ar(n) = rng.Areas(iArea).Rows(iRow).Row
            n = n - 1
            If n < 0 Then Exit For
        Next iRow
        If n < 0 Then Exit For
    Next iArea

    Dim j As Long
    For j = 0 To nValues - 1
        Debug.Print ar(j)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Looping filtered a list

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Filtered()

    Dim rng as Range, ID As Range, a As Range
    Dim ar(2) As Long, i As Integer, j As Integer
    
    ' apply filter
    With Sheet1
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, "A123"
        Set rng = .UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With

    ' count
    For Each a In rng.Areas
        For Each ID In a.Cells
            If ID.Row > 1 Then
                i = (i + 1) Mod 3
                ar(i) = ID.Row
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For j = 1 To 3
        Debug.Print ar((j + i) Mod 3)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice solution. Note that your area and id loop loops from the first visible row to the last visible. So it actually runs through **all** visible rows while it only needs to run through the last 3. If you turn this around from last visible to first visible row it is faster to find the last 3 rows (especially if there are many rows found). See my answer.

Comment: Thanks @CDP1802 ! your approach is also helpful and influenced my work.